# Timer for ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running a few ajax requests and I want to time them.

How can I get the number of seconds elapsed since the 1st request?

Comment: Have you done anything? Have you even try? It is not give me the code, you know!

Answer (score 3):

Create a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) when you set the first one. Create a new one whenever you want to have a point to compare to that start time. Then [compare them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#section_10).